# Exclude some categories from listing on the current post

Tags: posts, categories

this should be simple, but it seems it is not. I simply want to not list some of the current post's categories, just exclude them from the list of categories the current post belongs to

I use this for listing the current post's categories (but I am open to using whatever would work):

```
<?php the_category( ', ' ); ?>
```

and I tried this code on functions.php

```
    function my_category_filter($cats){
   //exclude these from displaying
   $exclude = array(4,);
   $Catds = array();
   foreach ($cats as$cat){
      if (!in_array($cat,$exclude)){$Catsa[] = $cat;}
   }
   return $Catsa;
}

add_filter('the_category','my_category_filter');
```

but no category will show if I use it. Maybe you can guide me into solving this?

thanks!

Comment: I posted an answer, but note that in your code, there's a typo - `$Catds` should be `$Catsa` ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is you're not using the proper hook because [`the_category`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/the_category/) is actually for modifying the HTML of the category list, and the 1st parameter for the hook is actually a *string* and not an array.

So the hook that you should have used is [`the_category_list`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/the_category_list/) where the 1st parameter is an array of terms/categories, but note that each item is an *object* (a `WP_Term` instance) and not a category ID.

And with your current code, you just need to make 2 changes:

1. Change the `add_filter()` to using `the_category_list` instead:

   ```php
   add_filter('the_category_list','my_category_filter');
   ```
2. In your `foreach`, change the `if` to using `$cat->term_id` instead:

   ```php
   if (!in_array($cat->term_id,$exclude))
   ```

So now your code should work correctly, but it also would work on any "current post", e.g. the one in the current loop, so you might need to add a condition to your function so that it only applies to specific posts.

Or you could actually manually generate the categories list/HTML, e.g. using [`get_the_category()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/get_the_category/):

```php
// ID's of the categories you want to be excluded.
$exclude = array( 4 );

// The categories list.
$cat_list = array();

foreach ( get_the_category() as $cat ) {
    if ( ! in_array( $cat->term_id, $exclude ) ) {
        $cat_list[] = '<a href="' . esc_url( get_category_link( $cat->term_id ) ) .
            '">' . $cat->name . '</a>';
    }
}

// Display a simple comma-separated list of links.
echo implode( ', ', $cat_list );
```

Then in your template, use the above code instead of the `the_category()`. That way, you can avoid messing with the categories list for other "current post".

Comment: I didn't manage to make the first code to work, but your second code works perfectly. thank you so much!